# post Nested data react hooks with asp core api

Tags: reactjs

Good day,

I'm triyng to post data with asp core api and react hooks and axios .
when I press submit to post data it's only post a part of data not all. I make post request in swagger It's working correctly , but in react there is an issue .

**Here is my api output :**

```html
{
  "studentId": 0,
  "studentName": "string",
  "classId": 0,
  "class": {
    "classId": 0,
    "classNo": 0
  },
  "subject": [
    {
      "subjectId": 0,
      "subjectName": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

**React code**

```html
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
export default function CreateStudent() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const [students,setStudent] = useState({
    studentName: "",
    classId:"",
    subject:[
              {
                subjectName: "",
                
              }
            ]
  });
  const [classes, setClass] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadClassess();
  }, []);

  const loadClassess = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get('https://localhost:7076/api/Classes');
    setClass(result.data);
  };

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setStudent({ ...students, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  
};

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post('https://localhost:7076/api/Students', students);
    
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow">
          <h2 className="text-center m-4">Inser New Student</h2>

          <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="studentName" className="form-label">
              Student Name
              </label>
              <input
                type={"text"}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Name"
                name="studentName"
                value={students.studentName}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="classId" className="form-label">
                   Select Classes
            </label>
            <select
             name="classId"
             value={students.classId}
             className="form-control"
             onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
            >
            <option value="">Select Class</option>
            {
             
             classes.map(classe =>{
                return(
                  <option key={classe.classId} value={classe.classId}>{classe.classNo}</option>
                )
              })
            }
            </select>
            
          </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="subjectName" className="form-label">
              Subject Name
              </label>
              <input
                type={"text"}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Subject Name"
                name="subjectName"
                value={students.subject.subjectName}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
            <Link className="btn btn-outline-danger mx-2" to="/">
              Cancel
            </Link>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

the issue is only post student name and class id , but subject name no

**Here is my database table output when execute select**

https://ibb.co/hmCkYZq

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is not correct since the `subject` in the student state is an array and the data is set based on the name of the input in the `onInputChange` function. The name of the input is used as a key.

```js
const onInputChange = (e) => {
  setStudent({ ...students, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

When you log the `students` state on submit you will see that it will look something like this.

```json
{
  "studentName": "ruben",
  "classId": "0",
  "subject": [
    {
      "subjectName": ""
    }
  ],
  "subjectName": "yes"
}
```

#### Solution 1

You could solve this by using refs for the inputs. In this case there is no need to use a state for the input values.

```js
const nameRef = useRef();
const classIdRef = useRef();
const subjectRef = useRef();

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  // create a student object with the values from the inputs
  const student = {
    studentName: nameRef.current.value,
    classId: classIdRef.current.value,
    subject: [
      {
        subjectName: subjectRef.current.value,
      },
    ],
  };
  // send it to the api
  await axios.post("https://localhost:7076/api/Students", student);
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input ref={nameRef} />
    <select ref={classIdRef}></select>
    <input ref={subjectRef} />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
);
```

#### Solution 2

If you prefer the state method you could create a seperate function that handles the changes from the subject input, or handle it with a simple if statement.

```js
const onInputChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.name === "subjectName") {
    return setStudent((prevStudent) => ({
      ...prevStudent,
      subject: [
        {
          subjectName: e.target.value,
        },
      ],
    }));
  }

  // for the other inputs
  setStudent((prevStudent) => ({
    ...prevStudent,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  }));
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
    <input
      name="studentName"
      value={students.studentName}
      onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
    />
    <select
      name="classId"
      value={students.classId}
      onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
    ></select>
    <input
      name="subjectName"
      value={students.subject[0].subjectName} // get value from index 0
      onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
    />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
);
```

EDIT:
To handle the subject as mentioned in the comments

```js
const [students, setStudent] = useState({
  studentName: "",
  classId: "",
});
const [subject, setSubject] = useState({
  subjectName: "",
});

const onInputChange = (e) => {
  setStudent((prevStudent) => ({
    ...prevStudent,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  }));
}

const onSubjectChange = (e) => {
  setSubject((prevSubject) => ({
    ...prevSubject,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  }));
}

const onSubmit = async (e) => {
  const postData = {
    ...students,
    subject: [subject]
  };
  await axios.post("your url", postData);
}

...

// on all the subject inputs you can use the on change like this
<input
  name="subjectName"
  value={subject.subjectName} // get value from index 0
  onChange={(e) => onSubjectChange(e)}
/>
```

Comment: many thanks It's working , but let's suppose if I have more inputs in subject , for ex : SubjectName,Degree, How to handle input on change then ?

Comment: One solution could  be to seperate the `subject` into its own state object and place it back into the array when sending the data to the api @IbrahimAl-Habian

Comment: How to do this please ?